# When does pipe need to be put in square brackets(matches) in foo.split()

Tags: java, regex

I recently came across a problem where I used split on a string with "|" as argument. Eg:

```
String foo = "Hello|World";
System.out.println(foo.split("|")[1]);
```

To my surprise the result printed was H. Knowing this was regex I surrounded it with [] and it worked correctly(printed out World).

My question is how do I know when the [] is necessary since I have used split on | without the [] before and it worked fine. My java version hasn't changed since. The only difference is that this was on an android project.

EDIT: I seem to be mistaken, just tried various ways of splitting on "|" without escaping or adding it to a set, but always the same result. I know I have split on pipes before, but seems I must've escaped or added to a set for the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pipe (`|`) is a saved regex symbol (which allows regular expression components to be logically `OR`-ed), but if you want to use it in its character context, you have to escape it **or** add it to a set (represented with `[]`).

Escaping example:

```
System.out.println(foo.split("\\|")[1]);
```

Adding the pipe to a set example:

```
System.out.println(foo.split("[|]")[1]);
```

Comment: A single atom character class is a waste, though. Better to go "the escape way"

Comment: I know about both these methods, my question was simply if there is anyway to know when they are necessary since I have used split with "|" as argument with no problems and working as intended(granted it isn't the best thing to do, just trying to understand whats different)

Comment: `Is there any way to know when they are necessary`? If you want `|` to be used as a character, not as a regex symbol, then you have to escape. Knowing if escaping is necessary depends on your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Try escaping pipe as split method takes regex as input and "|"(pipe) has special meaning in it, so use it like:

```
String foo = "Hello|World";
System.out.println(foo.split("\\|")[1]);
Output:
World
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a delimiter("\") for using special characters like | .

```
String foo = "Hello|World";
System.out.println(foo.split("\\|")[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape each character which has a special meaning in the regex. To get a list of all special characters have a look in the [Java API for the Pattern class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

For example: the `.`

```
- special meaning in the regex, it matched "Any character"
- if you want to disable this special meaning you have to escape it as `\.`
- as the backslash itself has also a special meaning you need to escape it as well,
  that's why the regex must be specified as `\\.`
```